# Замена определённого значения в столбце на переменную

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

У меня есть файл, состоящий из множества строк и столбцов.( Ниже кусок в котором нужно произвести замену)

Нужно заменить значение в 5-ом столбике, на переменную(вводимую вручную (числа от 0 до бесконечности)).

Пробовал через SED, но он иногда изменяет соседние столбцы, видимо из-за возникающих иногда совпадений.

```
line_no_1=`cat -n /home/user1/test.txt| grep 1.node|grep topon.S1| awk '{print $1}'` #ищу номер строки 
weight_1=`cat -n /home/user1/test.txt| grep 1.node|grep topon.S1| awk '{print $6}'` #ищу значение в столбце

read new_weight_1

sed -i "${line_no_1}"'s/'$weight_1'/'$new_weight_1'/' /home/user1/test.txt
```

Пробовал менять строку на изменённую строку - тоже не вышло.

```
number_line_no_1=`cat -n /home/user1/test.txt| grep 1.node|grep topon.S1 awk '{print $1}'` #ищу номер строки 
weight_1=`cat -n /home/user1/test.txt| grep 1.node|grep topon.S1| awk '{print $6}'` #ищу значение в столбце

line_no_1=`cat /home/user1/test.txt| grep 1.node|grep topon.S1` # записываю строку в 
переменную

read new_weight_1 

a=`cat /home/user1/test.txt| grep 1.node|grep topon.S1| awk '$5="'$new_weight_1'"'` # 
строчка с изменеённым весом


sed -i "${number_line_no_1}"'s/'$line_no_1'/'$a'/'  /home/user1/test.txt
```

[image: исходный файл]

Comment: Господи, ну используйте правильные инструменты для ваших задач. Это чистый CSV, поэтому python + pandas решат проблему быстро и с малым усилием. Если хочется изучить не очень нужный ЯП, то пишите на `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вас заинтересует этот сценарий:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

FILENAME="./test.txt"

declare -i nNode=1
declare new_weight=

read -r new_weight

awk -v nNode="${nNode}" -v new_weight="${new_weight}" '
    BEGIN {
        # Разделитель выходных столбцов будет табуляцией 
        OFS="\t"
    }
    # Фильтр по значениям первого и последнего столбцов 
    $1 == (nNode ".node") && $7 == ("topon.S" nNode) {
        # записать новое значение в столбец веса ...
        $5 = new_weight
        # ...и линия печати...
        print
        # ...и вычислить следующую строку 
        next
    }
    {
        # переформатировать строку с помощью OFS...
        $1 = $1
        # ...и линия печати
        print
    }
' \
< "${FILENAME}" \
> "${FILENAME}.tmp"

mv "${FILENAME}.tmp" "${FILENAME}"
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).